# Why doesnt Z increment?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I wanted to make a double loop, but for some reason Z doesnt increment.
What could be the reason for this and how do I fix it?

```
for (int i = 3; i < rowCountA + 4; i++)
  {
      for (int Z = 0; Z < rowCountA; Z++)
        {
        oWSheet.Cells[i, 2] = dtime_objA[Z].ToString() + "A";
        oWSheet.Cells[i, 3] = dx_objA[Z].ToString(); 
        oWSheet.Cells[i, 4] = dy_objA[Z].ToString();
        }              
  }
```

Comment: Z does increment, case closed? (you only get the strings from the last loop iteration though)

Comment: `for (int i = 3; i < rowCountA + 4; i++)` looks suspicious.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Please describe how it is behaving

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in your code, use the `Debug` mode and go in step by step to check the behavior and variable values.

Comment: Show the definition of `rowCountA`

Comment: Assuming `rowCountA` really is greater than `0`, then your loops will work.

Comment: @Icemanind if  accessing rowCountA has the side effect of changing the value of rowCountA, then the behavior as described could actually happen.

Comment: @HashPsi - Surely he doesn't have a property named `rowCountA`. That'd be the worst name ever for a property.

Comment: @Icemaning There is a lot of competition for choosing the 'worst name ever for a property'

Comment: Sorry, the problem wasnt stated clearly enough. I am making a software that plots points in a video and then puts the time, x coordinate, y coordinate in excel. dtime_objA[Z].ToString() + "A"; represents the time the point was plotted (Ignore the A right now). dx the x coordinate and dy the y coordinate.

RowcountA is the number of plots taken.

What I want to happen is to have row 3 to row 4+ number of plots to be filled with plot data. This plot data should fill columns 2 to 3.

However what is happening now, is that each row recurs the same data until 4+RowcountA number of rows.

Comment: @Icemanind whats wrong with this name? What would be a good name? I'm new to programming and I dont know difference between a good name and bad name like mine (I know that a complete random string of characters is bad, but isnt mine fairly relevent?).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want `Z` to keep incrementing after each iteration of the outer `for` loop.  When you hit the inner for loop, `Z` is reset to 0.  If you want `Z` to keep increasing after each iteration of the outer for loop, initialize it outside the loop:

```
int Z = 0;

for (int i = 3; i < rowCountA + 4; i++)
  {
      for ( ; Z < rowCountA; Z++)
        {
        oWSheet.Cells[i, 2] = dtime_objA[Z].ToString() + "A";
        oWSheet.Cells[i, 3] = dx_objA[Z].ToString(); 
        oWSheet.Cells[i, 4] = dy_objA[Z].ToString();
        }              
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't exactly what i was looking for but this answer gave the idea I needed. I've got over my problem.